# Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers can hang if Azul's Zulu is being used as JDK

Tags: eclipse, azul-zulu, azure-zulu

Sometimes Eclipse EE hangs on Windows Server 2008/2012 if Azul's Zulu is being used as JDK. Yet it works fine with Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse uses internal check for JVM vendor and adjusts memory settings accordingly. The current release of Eclipse is unaware of Zulu at the time of writing. JVM user may set memory adjustment manually by adding next setting to `eclipse.ini`

```
-vmargs -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```